# Error: Unable to read configuration file newrelic.js

Tags: node.js, webpack, newrelic, angular-universal

I’m getting this error:

```
Error: Unable to read configuration file newrelic.js. 
A base configuration file can be copied from 536 and renamed to in the 
directory from which you will start your application.
```

Project is Angular 7 SPA with SSR.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions:
The first by bj97301 on [official new relic forums](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/error-unable-to-read-configuration-file-newrelic-js/57659/8?u=62166ee949118b6c0f8c).

1. in my webpack config file, make newrelic external:

   externals: ['newrelic']
2. in my webpack config file, use commonjs as my output library target:

   output: { libraryTarget: 'commonjs'}
3. change newrelic.js to use exports. instead of export:

   was: export const config = {

   now: exports.config = {

This methods won't work if you want to deploy a whole package to remove server since you excluded the new relic package.
To solve this, you can use the second method.
As a workaround, change newrelic.js to override Environment variable instead of exporting the config.

e.g.

```
process.env.NEW_RELIC_NO_CONFIG_FILE = 'true';
process.env.NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME = 'YOUR APP NAME';
process.env.NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY = 'YOUR_KEY';
process.env.NEW_RELIC_LOG_LEVEL = 'warn';
process.env.NEW_RELIC_ALLOW_ALL_HEADERS = 'true';
console.log('New relic has been configurated.');
```

And you can remove the original config that was exported:

```
'use strict';
exports.config = {
  app_name: [],
  license_key: '',
  logging: {
    level: 'warning'
  },
  allow_all_headers: true
  }
```

Don't forget to require on your server.ts, simply add:

```
require('./newrelic');
```

I hope it would save someone some hours.